# Angular ngFor without an iterable. Need to Build the Iterable

Tags: javascript, angular, loops, iterator, ngfor

Having an *ngFor in Angular 2+ need to build the iterable (rows) through the creation of an array of n elements:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">

  </tr>
</table>
```

It's there a way of iterate over a number??.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is this no present? Do you need an index of row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an array of row indexes with a method of the component class:

```
public generateRowIndexes(count: number): Array<number> {
  let indexes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    this.indexes.push(i);
  }
  return indexes;
}
```

and call it in the template:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let rowIndex of generateRowIndexes(5)">
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

The code can be tested in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfopju).

Comment: I suppose that Array.from(Array(count).keys()); will be faster than the following: 

  createRows(num: number) {
    this.rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      this.rows.push(i);
    }
 
    return this.rows;
  }

Am I right??

Comment: @CryingFreeman - The traditional for loop is faster actually (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgd4nz)). I have put the `Array.from` expression in my answer because it is often suggested as the simplest (or shortest) way to create an array of indexes but, apparently, it is not the best if performance is an issue. I note that for 10000 records, both methods take less than 1 ms on my machine.

Comment: why the accessing function generateRowIndexes on the template the function is triggered more than once. Is this an angular issue??. Test with a console.log

Comment: It may be caused by Angular change detection mechanism. You can try `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (see [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)), with the row count as an `@Input()` parameter. With that in place, the change detection should be called only when needed. There are some catches with that optimization however (see [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/)). You may prefer to keep the standard strategy because of that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build a custom structure directive just for looping as many times as you want, it is a for-loop wrapped as directive.
The steps to doing this are:

- Step-1:
  In your module create a `loop.directive.ts` file.
- Step-2: In this directive file paste this code:

  ```
  import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
      selector: '[appLoop]'
    })
    export class LoopDirective {

  constructor(
    private viewContianerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
  ) {}

    @Input('appLoop') set render(loop: number){
      this.viewContianerRef.clear();

      for(let i=0; i<loop; i++){
        this.viewContianerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, {});
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Step-3: Now in your template file use `*appLoop="5"` if you want to loop 5 times or use a variable for example `numberOfLines` : `*appLoop="numberOfLines"`.

In the code you put in the question it will look like this, where `rows` is of type `number`:

```
<table>
  <tr *appLoop="rows">

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this syntax to set the index value into an attribute of the HTML element:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i"> // data-index attribute will be assigned index 

  </tr>
</table>
```